# asp.net mvc (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create Invalid URI The format of the URI could not be determined

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

Sorry, I figured it out.

The following code

```
(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("REPLACE_ME");
```

is throwing the following error

> "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined"

System.UriFormatException is thrown.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I figured it out. My web.config is incorrect.